# JsonArray to List in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, android-json

I have a problem with parsing JsonArray response.

I take JsonObject from JsonArray, parse it and set in entity message and then that message add to ArrayList.

Problem is that in ArrayList that I want to return I always have only one message. This must be some fundamental error but I cant find it.

```
public ArrayList<Message> getSearchInfo(String response) {
    ArrayList<Message> searchResult = new ArrayList<Message>();

    int jsonMessageId = -1;
    String jsonDate = "";
    String jsonText = "";
    String jsonAutor = "";
    String jsonSource = "";
    int jsonThemeID = -1;
    int jsonSourceID = -1;

    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);

        if (jArray != null) {

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                try {

                    JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Message m = new Message();
                    // Pulling items from the array

                    jsonMessageId = oneObject.getInt("MessageId");
                    jsonDate = oneObject.getString("CreatedDate");
                    jsonText = oneObject.getString("TextMessage");
                    jsonAutor = oneObject.getString("Autor");
                    jsonSource = oneObject.getString("Source");
                    jsonThemeID = oneObject.getInt("ThemeId");
                    jsonSourceID = oneObject.getInt("SourceId");

                    m.setMessageId(jsonMessageId);
                    m.setMessageText(jsonText);
                    m.setDate(jsonDate);
                    m.setAutor(jsonAutor);
                    m.setSource(jsonSource);
                    m.setThemeId(jsonThemeID);
                    m.setSourceId(jsonSourceID);

                    searchResult.add(m);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d("URL EXC", "Exception 2");
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return searchResult;
}
```

p.s. I use web-api as service and via android I take resources from service.
Any idea where is my mistake here?

Comment: post your json string plz.

Comment: searchResult = new ArrayList<Message>(); should be outside the for loop. You are basically initializing the arraylist in looping . Hence only one result.

Comment: I edited but I still have the same problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You redefine your list every time in the loop.

Change your code from

```
 JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);

        if (jArray != null) {

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                try {

                    searchResult = new ArrayList<Message>();
```

To

```
 JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);

        if (jArray != null) {
            searchResult = new ArrayList<Message>();

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                try {
```

Comment: I edited but still have the same problem... 1 message instead of 3 :(

Comment: Now I restarted eclipse and phone and it work :S Maybe it was problem that my app wasn't reinstalled properly but now everything is fine.